# ServiceStack.Interfaces : different versions for web and silverlight

Tags: servicestack

I uninstalled all of the service stack, and then re-installed, and I get different versions for ServiceStack.Interfaces library installed in web and silverlight application. I noticed that because I wanted to play with new api using IReturn on dtos, but it is not available in silverlight the way it installs. This is what properties window shows. This version also does not allow use of new API. For example JsonServiceClient only exposes Async methods that require url to be provided.

```
Silverlight:

Runtime Version: v4.0.30319
Version:         1.0.0.0

Web:

RuntimeVersion: v2.0.50727
Version:        3.9.43.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a new version 3.9.44 as of 6 days ago, that fixes the issue, although NuGet still pulls 3.9.43 version.